# Windows 7 Error 40

Tags: windows

На компе установлена Windows 7 SP1.
Выбивает не устранимую ошибку 40. Скриншот ниже.

Делал:

1) Проверку на вирусы.(ничего найдено)

2) Проверку на рекламные программы.(удален плагин в хроме.)

3) Чистку диска С от всякого электронного мусора.

4) Очистку виртуальной памяти.

5) sfc /scannow

6) Chkdsk C: /F /R и Chkdsk D: /F /R

7) Сброс настроек IE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]8) В диспетчере оборудование все нормально, все драйвера нормальные.

Ошибка не уходит, кто-то может помочь?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А у тебя случаем не geforce?

Comment: Нет geforce, там Intel.